# Solidity undefined

Tags: ethereum, solidity

I have a question when I use solidity to compile a simple contract.
It like that:

```
> web3.eth.getCompilers()
["Solidity"]
> source = "contract test { function multiply(uint a) returns(uint d) { return a * 7; } }"
"contract test { function multiply(uint a) returns(uint d) { return a * 7; } }"
> source
"contract test { function multiply(uint a) returns(uint d) { return a * 7; } }"
> clientContract = eth.compile.solidity(source).test
undefined
```

I don't know why the result is "undefined", what is wrong? I'm using it on the mac os.

Comment: Also have the same question in Ubuntu.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to [Greeter variables are all undefined and contract doesn't run](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/1293/87) `undefined` in JavaScript isn't a bad thing. Variable declarations always return `undefined`, its nothing to worry about.

So to answer your question, nothing is wrong, just proceed with your compiled `clientContract` and ignore the `undefined` return message.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I solve this question. That is not a wrong, is the solidity version change.